# PHP - array_push to create a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create an array which will have two key/value pairs for each user. I would like to add their user ID as well as their name.

Currently I have this:

```
<?php
    $userArray = array();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        array_push($userArray, $user->ID, $user->name);
    }
    print_r($userArray);
?>
```

This gives me the following:

```
Array ([0] => 167 [1] => Bill [2] => 686 [3] => Jim [4] => 279 [5] => Tom)
```

However, to make it easier to read and work with, I would prefer that it shows `user_id` and `user_name` as the keys, rather than just the index. I believe this is what's called a multidimensional array and would look more like this:

```
Array (
  0 => array(
    'user_id' => 167,
    'user_name' => 'Bill'
  ),
  1 => array(
    'user_id' => 686,
    'user_name' => 'Jim'
  ),
  2 => array(
    'user_id' => 279,
    'user_name' => 'Tom'
  )
)
```

My question is how would I build an array like this within my `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to create the new array and add it to the `$userArray`, I use `[]` instead of `array_push()` though...

```
$userArray[] = [ 'user_id' => $user->ID, 'user_name' => $user->name];
```

Answer (score 2):

you should be pushing a new array, like this :

```
 <?php
        $userArray = array();
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            array_push($userArray, ['user_id' => $user->ID, 'user_id' => $user->name]);
        }
        print_r($userArray);
    ?>
```